# A reference for $\nabla |u|^p = p\ \text{sgn}(u)|u|^{p-1}\nabla u$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be an open domain with nice boundary and $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. I believe that $|u|^p\in W^{1,1}$ with 
$$
\nabla |u|^p = p\ \text{sgn}(u)|u|^{p-1}\nabla u
$$ 
but couldn't find a good reference for this except for the case $p=1,2$.

The assumption in standard textbooks that I usually see regarding the chain rule for Sobolev functions, i.e.
$$
\nabla F(u) = F'(u)\nabla u,
$$
is that $F\in C^1$ with bounded derivative (or perhaps a Lipschitz function). However, here $F(t)=|t|^p$, which doesn't satisfy that assumption.

> Does anyone know where I can find this result in the literature?

I have a rough idea of how I would try to prove it myself, i.e. prove a similar result for $
F_\varepsilon(t) = (\varepsilon^2 + t^2)^{p/2}
$ first then take $\varepsilon \to 0$. Still, I want to know where I can find a reference for this result.

Comment: Could you provide any reference for $p=1,2$ ?

Comment: @S.Maths For $p=1$ you can find it in standard textbook like Evans' PDE or any book on Sobolev space. I've seen $p=2$ in some of the books as well and I believe someone wrote a proof on math.stackexchange.com.